# Append values from function to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I use this function:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

for i in range(X.shape[1]):
    clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, verbose=0, max_iter=1000).fit(X[:,i].reshape(-1,1), y)
    print(clf.score(X[:,i].reshape(-1,1),y))
```

and i get 4 values as output:

```
0.7466666666666667
0.5533333333333333
0.9533333333333334
0.96
```

But when i try to add these 4 values to list:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

for i in range(X.shape[1]):
    my_list = []
    clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, verbose=0, max_iter=1000).fit(X[:,i].reshape(-1,1), y)
    my_list .append(clf.score(X[:,i].reshape(-1,1),y))

print(my_list)
```

I get only last value:

```
[0.96]
```

I want to get :

```
[0.7466666666666667, 0.5533333333333333, 0.9533333333333334, 0.96]
```

How could i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to declare the list outside the loop so it doesn't get reset ever iteration!

```
my_list = []
for i in range(X.shape[1]):
    # you were resetting the list each time
    clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, verbose=0, max_iter=1000).fit(X[:,i].reshape(-1,1), y)
    my_list .append(clf.score(X[:,i].reshape(-1,1),y))
```

you could also use a list comprehension to avoid the confusion:

```
my_list = [LogisticRegression(random_state=0, verbose=0, max_iter=1000).fit(X[:,i].reshape(-1,1), y).score(X[:,i].reshape(-1,1),y) for i in range(X.shape[1])]
```

both store the list:

```
[0.7466666666666667, 0.5533333333333333, 0.9533333333333334, 0.96]
```